# How to change a chunk names generated by VuePress

Tags: vue.js, webpack, authorization, single-page-application, vue-cli

I want to use Vuepress for docs. 
Our doc is to be 100% static, and every content is private.

For business reasons, we should configure RBAC by routes. 
For instance, `/foo` is only accessible by `admin`, while `/bar` is accessible by both `admin` and `employee`.

However, it seems webpack output does not fit with route-based authorization.

[image]

Every compiled js files are in a single directory, `assets/js`. 
I can't apply route-based reverse proxy policy, for example, because I don't know which files belong to  which routes, like if `2.99194163.js` is for `/foo` or `/bar`. To know it, one has to read every compiled js files, which is not applicable.

This happens by default webpack configuration of Vuepress.

```
output: {
  filename: 'assets/js/[name].[chunkhash:8].js',
}
```

Would it be possible to organize by routes, like this?

```
assets/js
├── index
│   ├── app.0cb5ae60.js 
│   └── 10.059a7fe4.js
├── foo
│   ├── 11.62278c9d.js
│   ├── 12.9652ff3d.js
│   └── 13.c6c6b9fd.js
└── bar
    ├── 14.c8879eeb.js
    ├── 2.99194163.js
    ├── 3.7d54bf6f.js
    ├── 4.0c81bce7.js
    ├── 5.e47d5dbb.js
    ├── 6.004df3e0.js
    ├── 7.966197b8.js
    ├── 8.4bd54fba.js
    └── 9.78a40dc1.js
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`vuepress-plugin-named-chunks`](https://vuepress.github.io/en/plugins/named-chunks/#vuepress-plugin-named-chunks) plugin to modify the name and path of js chunks generated by VuePress for each page...

1. Install the plugin
2. Change `.vuepress\config.js`

```js
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    [
      "named-chunks",
      {
        pageChunkName: function(page) {
          let chunkPath = page.path.substring(1) + page.key;
          // console.log(chunkPath);
          return chunkPath;
        }
      }
    ]
  ]
};
```

Internally it is using `webpackChunkName` ["magic comment"](https://webpack.js.org/api/module-methods/#magic-comments)

If your `pageChunkName` returns string with not just file name but also with path, it is important to not include leading slash - `guide/readme.js` will work, `/guide/readme.js` will not.....

Comment: Thanks! I did exactly what you wrote. However, it still generates flattened files. No subdirectory is created by page. I want something like [this](https://github.com/vuejs/vuepress/pull/2126#issue-361789632)

Answer (score 0):

In your webpack.mix.js

**ADD This**

```
mix.webpackConfig({
  output: {
    chunkFilename: 'js/chunks/[name].[chunkhash].js',
  },
})
```